# Django Python import issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack with elasticsearch and elasticstack.

All this works fine locally but on heroku my elasticesearch settings are not picked up.

settings.py

```
..
try:
    from shopindex.local_settings import *
    from shopindex.es_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

es_settings.py

```
import os
from shopindex.settings import DEBUG, BASE_DIR
..
"synonyms_path": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "shopindex", "synonyms.txt")
```

Only sections of settings.py and es_settings.py that are relevant. Could it be a problem with circular imports?

Comment: What is heroku? Do you get any error message?

Comment: heroku is a cloud application hosting environment. No errors, it dies silently.